# Regex to include all spanish characters and number

Tags: java, regex

I have a Java app where I need to have a regex that replace ALL except characters and number (including the spanish characters as stressed vowels and ñ/Ñ) It's also needs to include some specific spacial characters.

I created the following regEx but it's removing also the stressed vowels which is not the idea

```
string.replaceAll("[^-_/.,a-zA-Z0-9 ]+","")
```

I just wanna accept those characters.. not others like æ, å or others..

Comment: Do you want to allow only a specific set of character marks? Like only ñ/Ñ, or all accents, including äöüèéâ and the like?

Comment: Yes, just that... I don;t want to get other characters like portugues, french, etc..

Comment: You do not "accept" anything or "get" with `replaceAll("...", "")` you "remove" the chars. What do you need to remove? Provide an example. What is the expected output for `"łąka123!@#$%^&*()_+"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `\p{L}` instead of `a-zA-Z`:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[^-_/.,\\p{L}0-9 ]+","");
```

The `\p{L}` matches all Unicode letters regardless of modifiers passed to the regex compile.

See a [Java test](https://ideone.com/y5IRhL):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("!@#Łąka$%^", "Word123-)(=+");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println("\"" + str.replaceAll("[^-_/.,\\p{L}0-9 ]+","") + "\"");
```

Output:

```
"Łąka"
"Word123-"
```

**Pattern details**: the `[^-_/.,\\p{L}0-9 ]+` pattern matches any char other than `-`, `_`, `_`, `/`, `.`, `,`, Unicode letter, ASCII digit and a space.

Note that with this solution, you will still remove Unicode digits, like `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`.

You may use [Mena's suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46850484/3832970) `\p{Alnum}` **but** with [`(?U)` embedded flag option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) to reall match all Unicode letters and digits:

```
string = string.replaceAll("(?U)[^-_/.,\\p{Alnum} ]+","");
```

To only remove Unicode letters other than common European letters, just add `À-ÿ` and subtract two non-letters, `×÷`, from this range:

```
string = string.replaceAll("(?U)[^-_/.,A-Za-zÀ-ÿ &&[^×÷]]+","");
```

Comment: Yeah, but I don;t wanna get the characters Łą or any other... I will update te question to make it clearer, thanks!

Comment: @Faabass *I created the following regEx but it's removing also the stressed vowels which is not the idea* - my regex does not remove `ł`, `ą`, etc.

Comment: @Faabass See the pattern details.

Comment: @Faabass Try another suggestion, `.replaceAll("(?U)[^-_/.,A-Za-zÀ-ÿ &&[^×÷]]+","")`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to include spanish special characters in a character class `[ ... ]`, there are only 7 after all.

I needed only lowercase characters, so instead of `[a-z]`, I used `[a-zñáéíóúü]` and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Alnum` script to replace all alphabetic characters and digits, including accented characters:

```
"[^-_/.,\\p{Alnum} ]+"
```

See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> \p{Alnum}     An alphanumeric character:[\p{Alpha}\p{Digit}]

Note that your replacement currently impacts all alphabetic characters, etc.

If you want to actually negate that custom class (thus replacing everything that's **not** defined in there), use:

```
"[^[-_/.,\\p{Alnum} ]]+"
```

(note the additional square brackets after the `^`, otherwise it would be interpreted as literal `^`).

**Edit**

You can furtherly narrow down to a subset of latin character blocks by using:

```
String s = "a1áŁą";
System.out.println(
    s.replaceAll("[^[-_/.,\\p{InBASIC_LATIN}\\p{InLATIN_1_SUPPLEMENT}0-9]]+","")
);
```

**Output**

```
Łą
```

Note that you will still have some non-Spanish characters in the Latin 1 supplement, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)).

If you want to restrict your requirements further, you will likely need to define your own (lenghty) character class with specific Spanish characters.

Comment: Yeah, but I don;t wanna get the characters Łą or any other... I will update te question to make it clearer, thanks!